# MySQL - How to get row number

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number

i have table like this:

```
tb_bid_test
+-------------+---------------------+
| Field       | Type                |
+-------------+---------------------+
| username    | varchar(20)         |
| poin        | bigint(20)          |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

then i run this query :

```
select @r := @r+1 as rank, z.* from(SELECT username, sum(poin) as jumlahPoin FROM `tb_bid_test` GROUP BY username order by jumlahPoin desc limit 3 )z, (select @r:= 0)y;
```

and the result :

```
+--------+------------+--------------+
| rank   | username   |  jumlahPoin  |
+--------+------------+--------------+
|   1    |        neo |      500     |
|   2    |     andhie |      348     |
|   3    |       john |      123     |
+--------+------------+--------------+
```

i want to get 1 row with username andhie, like this:

```
+--------+------------+--------------+
| rank   | username   |  jumlahPoin  |
+--------+------------+--------------+
|   2    |      andhie|      348     |
+--------+------------+--------------+
```

or others username and get the rank too, if i use the code before and add `where username ='andhie'` the rank is always 1. How to get the current rank based on their points?

Answer (score 1):

Select from your result username with value 'andhie'

```
create table tb_bid_test (username varchar(20),poin bigint(20));
insert into tb_bid_test values ('neo',500);
insert into tb_bid_test values ('andhie',348);
insert into tb_bid_test values ('john',123);


select * from (
select 
@r := @r+1 as rank, 
z.* 
from(SELECT username, sum(poin) as jumlahPoin FROM `tb_bid_test` 
GROUP BY username order by jumlahPoin desc limit 3 )z, 
(select @r:= 0)y 
  ) as t where username ='andhie'
```

[Try the fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/705f97/10)

Comment: you are welcome..if it solved you can select as answer

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
Select * from (select @r := @r+1 as rank, z.* from(SELECT username, sum(poin) as jumlahPoin FROM `tb_bid_test` GROUP BY username order by jumlahPoin desc limit 3 )z, (select @r:= 0)y;) where username="andhie"
```

Comment: get error because of  ";" after "y". After fix that, this code works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use nested query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT @r := @r + 1 AS rank, z.*
        FROM (
                SELECT username, SUM(poin) AS jumlahPoin
                FROM tb_bid_test
                GROUP BY username
                ORDER BY jumlahPoin 
                DESC limit 3
        ) z,
        (SELECT @r := 0) y
    ) tbl
WHERE username = "andhie"
```

Comment: get error because of space between "sum (poin)" and ";" after "y". After fix that this code works thanks